# Оператор присвоения PHP

Tags: php

Имеется цикл.

```
 foreach ($res->price as $item) {
        if (продукт существует) {
        echo 'Обновлен продукт и информация';
        } else {
         echo 'Добавлен продукт и информация';
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно весь этот отчет отправить на почту.
Пробовал так:

```
$summary = 'Result: ';
foreach ($res->price as $item) {
            if (продукт существует) {
            $summary .= 'Обновлен продукт и информация';
            } else {
             $summary .= 'Добавлен продукт и информация';
            }
        }
var_dump($summary);
```

В общем, $summary должен содержать в итоге то, что я отправлю потом на почту.
Но скрипт выдает ошибку 504 timeout.

Как реализовать?

Comment: а что скрывается за `продукт существует`?

Comment: Происходит сверка через БД. if(mysql_num_rows($edit) > 0) {

Comment: возможно большая выборка из БД?

Comment: Ну через echo то выводит все нормально

Comment: тогда попробуйте отправить почту разными способами

Comment: возможно sendmail лоче/не отвечает/еще чтото

Comment: Проблема не в отправке почты. До момента отправки почты в переменной вместо данных, которые надо отправить скрипт выбивается с 504 ошибкой. Если автор верно изложил свой вопрос. Попробуйте провести эксперимент с ограничением выборки из бд. можете увеличивать постепенно таймауты в настройках сервера, что найти подходящее значение.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы циклом проходите по неверной сущности. Если $res у вас ссылка на результат выборки из БД, тогда цикл должен выглядеть так:

```
foreach ($res as $item) {
     if (продукт существует) {
          $summary .= 'Обновлен продукт и информация';
     } else {
          $summary .= 'Добавлен продукт и информация';
     }
}
```